# Is Drinax Part 8 not released yet, or am I just having trouble downloading it?

Tags: traveller

The Mongoose Website clearly says that Part 8 is out, but it is only available to download as a Ebook and will not let me download just Part 8. Does anyone know whether this is a general issue, or if it's just me?

Comment: You have now created *three* different accounts: [one](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/19623/james-marshall), [two](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/19675/james-marshall), and this one makes [three](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/21709/james-marshall). Please [have them merged](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 4):

All eight parts of *The Pirates of Drinax* have been compiled into a single zipped download of the PDFs. You can get it [here from Mongoose's online store](http://www.mongoosepublishing.com/campaign-2-the-pirates-of-drinax.html) for the low, low price of $0.00 plus the time it takes to download 10.2 MB.